# Is xPath the preferred way to target an element during Selenium testing or a fallback?

Tags: selenium, xpath

Whilst using Selenium IDE to set up a test I noticed the app picks a locator for an element (seemingly) randomly. Sometimes a class, sometimes an ID, and sometimes an *xPath*.

So is xPath the "fall back"? Maybe it is preferred that an ID should be used (if available) for more reliable testing. Or is it the other way around? That xPath is in fact the gold standard for finding elements on a page?

I can tweak the tests you see, and I wondered whether I should err towards ID's or xPaths.

Comment: Whether XPath expressions are more reliable or stable depends on the nature of the expressions.  Can you please show some examples of "class, sometimes an ID, and sometimes an xPath"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "preferred" way of locating the elements is using their [ID attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp), as per [Choosing a Location Strategy](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#choosing-a-location-strategy) chapter:

> **Using an element ID or name locator is the most efficient in terms of test performance, and also makes your test code more readable, assuming the ID or name within the page source is well-named**. XPath statements take longer to process since the browser must run its XPath processor. XPath has been known to be especially slow in Internet Explorer version 7. Locating via a link’s text is often convenient and performs well. This technique is specific to links though. Also, if the link’s text is likely to change frequently, locating by the  element would be the better choice.

On the other hand, XPath is the most powerful option as:

- it has full access to the page [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)
- you're able to traverse DOM [Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes) and query elements children/parents/siblings, ancestors, etc.
- you're able to apply [functions and operators](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) like [contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains), [starts-with()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with), `and`, `or`, `not`, etc. so you're able to locate any element at any page using XPath which is not the case for other selector strategies.

Comment: That docs link, which I had overlooked, even goes as far as to say "Sometimes though, you must use an XPath locator. If the page source does not have an ID or name attribute you may have no choice but to use an XPath locator." - Which I think answers the question adequately. Thanks very much.

Comment: That page likely hasn't been updated in YEARS. If you listen to any of the Selenium contributors speak at conferences, you will hear them state over and over to avoid XPath. There's no mention in that article at all about CSS selectors. You should prefer ID then CSS selector then XPath (and then only when you need to find an element by contained text or need to do DOM traversal).

Comment: @DmitriT Your last bullet point is not correct. CSS selectors can do all of those things. See [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview). Also, all locator options have full access to the DOM, they just search it for different things so I'm not sure what that statement means. Using ID searches the entire DOM but only for elements that contain the desired ID.

Comment: @JeffC could you match a cell in a first row from a HTML table which belongs to "foo" header using CSS selector, please (assuming the position of the relevant `th` tag may change)?

Comment: That's bullet point 2, not 3. I didn't say CSS selectors can do absolutely everything that XPath can do but it can do most of it... especially all of the things listed in point 3. The two things XPath can do that CSS selectors cannot are finding element by contained text and DOM navigation (like the example you gave in your question).